# EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT,subcode=0xe7ffdefe) release build issue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm getting the following error when I create a release build of my application:

**EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT,subcode=0xe7ffdefe)**

It all works fine when it is a "Debug" build, no errors at all.

I've managed to pin it down to the following code, and it seems to be when returning the Int8 value.

```
    //sort the data for the trigger value
    func triggerDataSort(data: NSData) -> Int8 {

    var myval:Int8!
    data.getBytes(&myval, length:sizeof(Int8))
    println(myval)
    return myval

}
```

I'm a bit confused as to why or what is causing it? All I see is (lldb) kick in and no error other than the EXC_BREAKPOINT mentioned earlier.

Thx.

Comment: When `(lldb)` kicks in type `bt all` and post the results.

Answer (score 1):

I changed to this and it now works ok... I think myval was nil and causing me issues... even though the print was showing a value.

```
    var myval:Int8 = 0
    data.getBytes(&myval, length:sizeof(Int8))
    println("myval value is \(myval)")
    return myval
```

Comment: I am using similar code to this but using an Int instead of Int8. Could that be causing issues you think?